# Windows Batch folder exist and folder not exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, exists

Have a need where we need to delete zip files that exist under a specific folder at 100 days old.  All other zip files in the other folders, we can delete that are 30 days old.  This would be easy if the files were a specific name, unfortunately we can only do this by folder name.

In the end result we will be using one of these techniques with FORFILES as we don't have to do a lot of logic programming in script.

Searched and did find how to do this and works OK, but the processing of the script is very slow..  Pretty much at this point, everything in the **"NOT" somefolder condition** is what takes quite a while to complete.  Have done this with VBScript and PowerShell, but really want to get back to Batch Scripting for this.

[BAT script to search directory for folders that match an input name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188002/bat-script-to-search-directory-for-folders-that-match-an-input-name)
and as dbenham admits, again this is very slow.  Also, did not like the fact that it does not show all folders in the "not" condition for the ones it does not find
He also states, that if you want to do extensive file/folder searching redirecting to a output file, maybe the best solution

This does work, but does not show the "not found" or the folders it would list..

```
dir /s /a-d c:\windows\*system32* >nul && (echo found it) || (echo not found)
```

This works to find all folders with system32 on a drive

```
dir /b /ad /s "c:\system32"
```

This works to look for folders that **DO HAVE** system32 within the results which are pretty quick too

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /ad /s c:\ ^| findstr /I /C:"system32"') DO echo %%G
```

We want to show all folders that **DO NOT HAVE** system32 within and in testing and redirecting to result.txt file, it created a 11.9MB file and will take quite a while to complete especially on a whole drive

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /ad /s c:\ ^| findstr /I /V /C:"system32"') DO echo %%G
```

[How do I search for the directory of a file given its name using a batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932919/how-do-i-search-for-the-directory-of-a-file-given-its-name-using-a-batch-script?rq=1)
Not quite sure about this one

```
for /r c:\ %%F in (system32) if exist "%%F" echo %%~dpF
```

Playing around we get

```
For /F %%A IN('dir /s /a-d "c:\windows\*system32*") do && (echo found it) || (echo not found)
```

Are there any other ideas or Suggestions out there?

Comment: You are using a filespec of *.zip right?  That will limit the number of files thet **forfiles** has to process and reduce the time taken.  You do this once a day I guess, and it can be done in the background, right?  How long does it take?

Comment: It would be once a day and it is Zip files, but the folder name is what I need to look for first.  If it is one name of a folder, I need to delete the zip files after 100 days..  All other folders, we can delete the Zip files after 30 days.   I did try the following bit of code from Microsoft, which did not seem to work either..
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.asp

`forfiles /p c:\WINDOWS /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c if @isdir==true, if @file==System32 echo @file is a directory"`

Comment: Is the special directory a single folder, or is is a tree of folders that need to be excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search in `c:\files` and below, and delete zip files by the following criteria:

In the folder called `Special folder` it will delete them if they are 100 days or older
otherwise it will delete them if they are 30 days or older.

Any zip file in the folders below the `Special folder` will be deleted at 30 days and older.

Test it before use.

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\files" %%a in (*.zip) do (
   for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
      if /i "%%~nxb"=="Special folder" (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /d -100 /c "cmd /c del @path"
        ) else (
         forfiles /p "%%~dpa." /m "%%~nxa" /d -30  /c "cmd /c del @path"
      )
   )
)

pause
```